# filtering in R's dplyr with 2 conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R, it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 
                is_private = c("y","y","n","n","n","y"), 
                insurer =c("uhc","aetna","medicare","medicare","medicaid","oscar"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I'm trying to use `dplyr::filter` to get a list of unique names of `df$insurer` for only those whose value of `df$is_private` is 'n'.

What I want is a list or df that looks like this:

```
uniques
-------
medicare
medicaid
```

I keep trying things like:

```
pub_list <- df$insurer %>%
  filter(df$is_private == "n") %>%
  unique()
```

But all I get are error messages that say `no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distinct()` might be better.

```
df %>%
  filter(is_private == "n") %>%
  distinct(insurer)
```

Comment: Everyone I know named Tony rules - another one in the books. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
unique(df[df$is_private == "n", "insurer", drop = F])
```